Skill script-How to update new value for dynamically created variable
I have to check layout properties, for each property found i need to get the value and cell name added in a list or table
Ex:
property_l='("pl1" "pl2" "pl3") foreach(pl property_l set(stringToSymbol(strcat("tab_" stringToSymbol(pl))) makeTable(pl 0))
foreach(pl property_l if(pl==pl1 then tab_pl[cvid~>cellname]=cvid~>prop~>value );if );foreach
Above code does not work since it does not evaluate pl in tab_pl, is there a way to evaluate left hand operator?
